# SNMP - AgentX master disconnected us during getnext & walk

Tags: linux, c++, embedded, snmp

My observations are as follows.
I can run an SNMP get request as many times on as many different oids, and the request will return the value. But as soon as run a GetNext request, I see

```
NET-SNMP version 5.9.1 AgentX subagent connected
registered debug token agentx/subagent, 1
```

I've tried to use the snmpd configuration options maxGetbulkRepeats & maxGetbulkResponses which seem to resolve the issue for snmpwalk sometimes(not always) while there is still always an issue with manual getNext requests.

I'm really at a loss for trouble shooting this issue. I don't see any error logs other then, the error posted above, although I have this a couple times:

```
lock in _callback_lock sleeps more than 100 milliseconds in snmp_unregister_callback
netsnmp_assert lock_holded < 100 failed callback.c:143 _callback_lock()
```

But this seems to be a race condition here when both master and subagent shutdown at the same time, so it is likely caused due to whatever issue that is causing the agent to disconnect in the first place.

The snmp agent I am developing is using c++ with the net-snmp library (v5.9.1).
I have seen the same issues, using a mib browser and running the snmp requests on a ubuntu CLI.

Open to any and all suggestion for debugging!